# python: subprocess.communicate not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, subprocess

I want to input one argument to the subprocess.communicate, but it always be out of my expects.
the folder tree:

```
├── file1
├── file2
├── main.py
```

the content of main.py:

```
import subprocess
child = subprocess.Popen(["ls"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE,  universal_newlines=True)
filepath = '/Users/haofly'
child.communicate(filepath)
```

whatever i change the filepath to, the result only lists current folder(file1,file2,main.py).

Is I misunderstanding the communicate? How I send data to the Popen?

And how about ssh command if i want to send password?

`subprocess.Popen(['ssh', 'root@ip'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot 'pipe' data into `ls` - it lists directories based on the provided CLI arguments - but you should be able to use `xargs` to achieve what you want (essentially passing your folder as an argument to `ls`) if you don't want to provide it with the command itself:

```
import subprocess
child = subprocess.Popen(["xargs", "ls"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
filepath = '/Users/haofly'
child.communicate(filepath)
```

Comment: thanks, it works. how about ssh command, how i send the password to the process

Comment: Do yourself a favor and get the `pxssh` module for that. If you really want to do it through `Popen` directly without any 'expect' modules you might pull it by writing directly to the processes' STDIN (you might want to do add a slight delay before that, to give some time to SSH): `child.stdin.write("your_password\n"); child.stdin.flush()`

Comment: Yes, I don't want any 'expect' modules, i don't know how to add the delay for it.

Comment: It won't work even with a delay (it's automatically added when calling `.communicate()`) - OpenSSH doesn't use STDOUT/STDIN to communicate, instead it talks directly to the calling terminal. You'd actually need to set up a whole pseudo terminal in order to do what you want without the `pexpect` module (which uses `pty` as a pseudo terminal) which is out of bounds for a SO question. Why wouldn't you want to use modules that were already written by people who had the same problem as you?

Comment: Yeah, I think so. In fact, I just want to know weather there is one way to work, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the a shell parameter in your `Popen` call:

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.wait()
print process.returncode
```

'ls' is probably not the best command to illustrate the concept, but if you want to pass in arguments to a command you would have to do something similar to this:

```
cmd = ['cmd', 'opt1', 'optN']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate('args')
print out
```

Comment: how about ssh command, how i send the password to the process

Answer (score 1):

When you use `ls` manually, do you type `ls` alone, hit Enter, and then type in the filepath in response to a prompt?  That's how you're trying to use it here - the parameter to `.communicate()` becomes the subprocess's standard input, which in fact `ls` ignores completely.  It wants the directory to list as a command-line parameter, which you would specify as `["ls", filepath]`.